# Recommended reading about Holographic Principle

Tags: resource-recommendations, holographic-principle

Please recommend papers/books/blogs for someone trying to learn about the Holographic Principle, assuming that person has knowledge of the undergraduate mathematics and physics major level.

Comment: "The Black Hole War" by Leonard Susskind is a good popular science book on this, but way below the maths you're looking at (almost no math in fact, but still worth a look)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The Holographic Principle" 
Professor Raphael Bousso
REVIEWS OF MODERN PHYSICS, VOLUME 74, JULY 2002 (published August 2002)
50pp review, with appendices giving a tutorial on the concepts of general relativity that are used.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0203101